# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery with Poltergeist/Capybara

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

### What I'm trying to Do

I'm trying to use capybara with poltergeist to log into amazon at this URL...

```
https://developer.amazon.com/rp/sales.html
```

Simple enough, except that when I try to submit the form, I get the error...
    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery ...

However, the source for jQuery is on the page and should have been loaded.

The code I'm using to log in is this...

```
  visit "https://developer.amazon.com/rp/sales.html"
  fill_in('ap_email', with: user)
  fill_in('ap_password', with: password)
  click_on('signInSubmit-input')
```

Submit triggers a javascript call to validate input. This uses jQuery and when it does, the error is thrown.

### What I Expected

I expected that when I visited the login page, that jquery would have been loaded with the other javascript on that page.

I have no idea why jQuery would not be loaded at this point.  Phantomjs would have loaded the page and loaded the jQuery referenced on the page, no?

### Things I've Tried

**Timing Issue?**
 - Added sleep after the visit.

**Configuration Issue?**

- My Current Configuration

  ```
  include Capybara::DSL
  Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
  Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, phantomjs: Phantomjs.path)
  end
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false
  ```
- Attempting to Force jQuery to Load

  ```
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app,
                                phantomjs: Phantomjs.path,
                                extensions: ["handlers/jquery.js"])
  ```

I've tried quite a few things in an attempt to get my head around what's going on but I'm coming up empty.

Any thoughts on where I might look or what may be going on would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably the best asked question by a new user that is still not answerable without guessing.

Comment: It might be related to SSL and web security. I don't know how this is done in capybara, but you try to pass --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false to phantomjs

Comment: Good thought, Artjom, but it didn't help. I think I need to take a different tack and see if a different driver has the same issue. I did try webkit and it had the same error, but maybe actually watching what's going on might reveal something else.

Comment: Using selenium with FF, I don't get this error. So, the problem has to be in how I've set things up.  Still looking.

Comment: No, it's almost certainly a problem with PhantomJS. It always has some kind of problem. Have you tried using PhantomJS 2?

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/58  that I think is pretty much the same problem I'm having.  phantomjs is set to '--ssl-protocol=any' as suggested, though I suspect it's a related.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.8 so I'll check out 2.0 soon. I may have to abandon phantomjs in any case. I need to download files, and working around that limitation is proving to be painful.

Comment: Well, got some idea of the problem. It's not phantomjs, I think.  Amazon is using openid (I believe), and this link shows how to do it using mechanize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783179/cannot-login-to-amazon-with-ruby-mechanize    With that hint, I'm pretty sure I can get this working now.

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is on the page you most likely have to use an evaluate function to enter the context of the page. CasperJS has this diagram http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/_images/evaluate-diagram.png
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html

> The execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom
>   object and it can't probe its own setting.

Answer (score 0):

The execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom object and it can't probe its own setting.